# Accidently changed CNAME entries for "autodiscover" and "_domainconnect", will that hurt my website?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cname, dns-servers, 1and1

I am an absolute noob in web development, but I have a Wordpress site and while I was trying to verify my website for Youtube, I made a mistake and changed 2 CNAME entries on my 1und1.de (german version of 1and1.com) webhosting page under "DNS settings".

These CNAME entries were titled "autodiscover" and "_domainconnect" but I forgot their original value.
I contacted the 1and1 support, but the guy on the other side didn't really have a clue and said that I should know what these entries are (even though I didn't add them, they were there by default).

The phone call lead to no solution but he implied that I could delete them, and so I did. I deleted these entries and my page is still working, but I don't know if I did any damage under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need either of these resource records for your website to work correctly.

You only need the `autodiscover` resource record if you’re using the email service provided by *1und1.de* with your domain name. This is documented in their English language version at [What is Autodiscover?](https://help.1and1.com/e-mail-and-office-c37589/e-mail-clients-c85092/what-is-autodiscover-a792599.html). In my experience, `autodiscover` records are only used by MS Outlook to access email accounts on MS Exchange server. See also, [What Is An Autodiscover Record And Why Do I Need It?](https://kb.intermedia.net/Article/1306).

The `_domainconnect` record is used to implement the [Domain Connect](https://www.domainconnect.org/) standard which aims to make management of a domain name easier for users who do not know much about DNS.

Comment: Thank you for the detailled answer. I read the Domain Connect link, but I don't quite understand what I am losing without the CNAME entry.
Also in terms of email, I have an info@mydomain.com email adress that is connected with my gmail account. Will this be affected in any way?

Comment: @FlorianWalther If you're modifying DNS records directly, I imagine you're not using Domain Connect so you shouldn't worry about it. If you're using Gmail (or forwarding to Gmail) for you domain's email, you don't need the Autodiscover resource record.